# reading json data through Apache Spark

Tags: java, json, apache-spark

i am trying to read sample Json file through Apache Spark, during this process i observed one thing is that you need to keep entire json object into single line. If i keep entire json object into single line,code is working well otherwise getting exception.

This is my json data:

```
    [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "An ice sculpture",
        "price": 12.50,
        "tags": ["cold", "ice"],
        "dimensions": {
            "length": 7.0,
            "width": 12.0,
            "height": 9.5
        },
        "warehouseLocation": {
            "latitude": -78.75,
            "longitude": 20.4
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "A blue mouse",
        "price": 25.50,
        "dimensions": {
            "length": 3.1,
            "width": 1.0,
            "height": 1.0
        },
        "warehouseLocation": {
            "latitude": 54.4,
            "longitude": -32.7
        }
    }
]
```

This is my code:

```
SparkSession session = new SparkSession.Builder().appName("JsonRead").master("local").getOrCreate();
        Dataset<Row> json = session.read().json("/Users/mac/Desktop/a.json");
        json.select("tags").show();
```

In case of small datasets its okay, is any other way to process large json datasets?

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`tags`' given input columns: [_corrupt_record];

Answer (score 2):

see the document:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets

**JSON Datasets**

*Note that the file that is offered as a json file is not a typical JSON file. Each line must contain a separate, self-contained valid JSON object. As a consequence, **a regular multi-line JSON file will most often fail.***